# Ограничение доступа к файлу C#

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы

Есть софтина которая активно логирует действия и записывает их в обычный файл. 
Как убрать ограничение доступа или сделать доступ только приложению, чтобы не было ситуации когда банальный просмотр каталога с файлом приводит к ошибке доступа

> Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "D:\Perforce\Credits\ReloadDataForJurist\ReloadDataForJurist\bin\Debug\Logs\log.log", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.

При этом ошибка плавающая. Он может записать и 1000 записей и свалится а может и 20.

Comment: Забыл написать Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: А может лучше воспользоваться готовым решением? Log4Net, например

Answer (score 2):

Не надо каждый раз открывать и закрывать файл. Один раз откройте и пишите в него сколько влезет. Ось не даст никому ничего сделать с этим файлом (точнее, позволит только то, что вы явно разрешите флагами `FileShare`), и у вас права на запись не отберёт.

Ну и сама ось обычно не блокирует файл на запись при просмотре папки. Это наверняка какой-нибудь антивирус резвится.